# How to get data from two tables of a call (function) double-use true or false?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a function, responsible for knowing if a user made the purchase correctly (`complete`) or if the status of the purchase is (`incomplete`).

This function is with a single query.

```
function checkOrderComplete($con,$id_product,$id_user){
  $res = false; // the default result
  $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT status FROM order WHERE id_product=? AND id_user=? AND status=? limit 1"); 
  $stmt->bind_param("iis",$id_product,$id_user,$status); 
  $status='complete'; 
  $stmt->execute();

  $stmt->store_result(); 

  if ($stmt->num_rows ===1){
    $res = true;
  } else {
    $res = false;
  }
  return $res;

}
```

---

Now I have added a new table called ***order_details***

```
id_order_product  order_date  id_product  quantity  price   id_order
       1             -----          2        1       10.00     18
       2             -----          6        1       50.00     18
```

***Order***

```
id_order id_user  status   
  18        3    complete
```

So what I want to achieve is the same functioning of the function you can realize before, it took into account the status of the purchase if it was completed or not, and the id of the product, and the id of the user who made the purchase.

Then perform the following procedure but it shows me errors in the `$stmt->bind_param("isi",$id_user,$status,$id_product);`

The query:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT order.status, order.id_user, order_details.id_product FROM order inner join order_details ON order.id_user=? order.status=? order_details.id_product=? LIMIT 1");
```

How do I obtain the same values mentioned from the two tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `JOIN` is not not properly formatted.  The way to define a `JOIN` is to use the `ON` keyword to define what fields should be equal to perform the `JOIN`.  Like so:

```
SELECT order.status,
       order.id_user,
       order_details.id_product
FROM order
INNER JOIN order_details ON order_details.id_order = order.id_order
WHERE order.id_user = ?
  AND order.status = ?
  AND order_details.id_product = ?
```

Then bind your parameters as required.